# Facebook Graph API not returning past events correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a problem with the *facebook graph api*.

I tried calling the events with

```
$events = $facebook->api('/{Page_ID}/events?');
```

but I am only receiving current events. 
So events from past are mostly missing.I have tried adding parameters with `SINCE/UNTIL` and `LIMIT` as also but nothing changes. Even in the Graph explorer I can't browse to past events with the previous or next link.

All events are public and all events guestlist are shown as well. I have all permissions and also the right access_token.

I remember that some months ago I did not have this issue.

I am very grateful for any hints to this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while. I finally managed to get past events using a FQL query:

```
              $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => 'xxxxxxx',
                'secret' => 'xxxxxxx'
              ));
              $page_id = 'xxxxxxxxx';
              $date = '2000-08-24T02:07:43';
              $params = array(
                  'method' => 'fql.query',
                  'query' => "SELECT name, start_time, end_time, location,attending_count,venue,unsure_count,eid
                    FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid =".$page_id." AND start_time >= '$date'   )
                    ORDER BY start_time DESC ",
              );
              $events = $facebook->api($params);
```